# Can't launch Firefox Developer Edition OS X 10.10.2

Tags: firefox-developer-edition

Tried to launch Firefox Developer Edition installed from firefox-38.0a2.en-US.mac.dmg. But with no success:

[image]

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I managed to launch it with `/Applications/FirefoxDeveloperEdition.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --ProfileManager` but it still repeats the issue while be launched by clicking on app icon.

Comment: Have you tried downloading it again?

Comment: Several times within a few days :(

Comment: Update with info about command line launching

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to try re-downloading it because the file is "damaged", so that's what you have to try to do, if not, try downloading it off another website.

Comment: The same issue both on en_US and ru_RU versions. Seems re-downloading can NOT fix the issue.

Comment: @erop Well, I can't say much then. Maybe there is something wrong in your system settings or something like this. I don't know.